# Передать значение в функцию

Tags: php, wordpress

Функция

```
<?php
  $img_id = get_post_custom_values('img');
  foreach ( $img_id as $key => $value ) {
echo $value;
  }
?>
```

возвращает мне число - id изображения. Нужно через запятую записать 4 подобных id  в '' следующего кода

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[gallery ids='']'); ?>
```

Comment: ровно четыре, или Вам для примера хотя бы четыре?

Comment: @Wayer у записи 4 подобных параметра - img1,..., img4
все их надо передать в виде строк, через запятую

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
<?php

  $img_id = get_post_custom_values('img');
  foreach ( $img_id as $key => $value ) {
    if(++$i > 4)
      break;
    $string_with_ids .= $value;
    if($i < 4)
      $string_with_ids .= ',';
  }
?>
```

Comment: этот код я вставляю в кавычки?

Comment: прошу прощения, не дописал.

`<?php echo do_shortcode("[gallery ids='$string_with_ids']"); ?>`